# How to show only the comment form, not the comments

Tags: comments

Right now in Drupal, at the end of each article, there are the comments which users has put on that article and also the comment form. I just want to have the comment form at the end of each article, I do not want the comments be shown at the end of each article. Does any body know how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `hook_node_view()` and check for `$node->type == 'article'` and `$view_mode=='full'` then unset the comments as follows

```
unset($node->content['comments']['comments']);
```